# Git + Jenkins - build on main master branch throws "fatal: reference is not a tree"

Tags: git, github, jenkins, build

I've got the Git and Git Pull Request Builder plugins installed on my Jenkins server, and I've got web hooks created on GitHub to auto trigger my builds whenever: (1) a pull request is opened, or (2) a merge happens to the main repository from someone's fork.

I'm seeing an intermittent issue when MERGE builds are performed (scenario 2 above) where Git throws this exception:

```
FATAL: Could not checkout d68a985c98badf605b12b63424beb08776ab2752
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Could not checkout    d68a985c98badf605b12b63424beb08776ab2752
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$8.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1907)
at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:1060)
at hudson.scm.SCM.checkout(SCM.java:485)
at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1275)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:610)
at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:86)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:532)
at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1741)
at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:410)
Caused by: hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "git checkout -f d68a985c98badf605b12b63424beb08776ab2752" returned status code 128:
stdout: 
stderr: fatal: reference is not a tree: d68a985c98badf605b12b63424beb08776ab2752

at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1640)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.access$500(CliGitAPIImpl.java:62)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$8.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1899)
... 10 more
```

The commit in question (d68a985c98badf605b12b63424beb08776ab2752) is in fact from a pull request on someone's fork that has not been merged into the main repository yet, so why on earth is Git trying to pull this commit down when performing a build on my main repository's master branch that people fork.

The refspec I am using for the build of my master branch on the main repository is:

```
+refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/origin/master
```

This one has really dumbfounded me, and I don't know even where to start. I saw similar issues such as https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/617 but it is not obvious to me if they are related.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: did you have find a solution to this issue?

Comment: I never got to the bottom of it. The server was since switched to use the newer GitHub plugins such as https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/GitHub+Branch+Source+Plugin and things work fine.